# How to remove the reference to the bigbluebutton.com website?

Tags: bigbluebutton

I am currently working on the implementation of the bigbluebutton software and I require hide the links to the web page bigbluebutton, because they appear as methods of contact and this may confuse users of the system, because the contact methods should relate to the company providing the service and not bigbluebutton.

How I can hide these links?

Link in the chat area:

[image: Print screen]

Link in the footer area:

[image: Print screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. How to disable link in Chat area:

Modify /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/bigbluebutton/web-inf/class/bigbluebutton.properties.

Set "defaultWelcomeMessageFooter" property to empty or perhaps html break tag. Restart nginx to see effect.

2. How to modify the footer:

For this, you will first have to setup a development environment, following url explains how to do this.
https://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/wiki/081DevelopingBigBlueButton

Then change “bbb.mainshell.copyrightLabel2” property in 
~/dev/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton–client/locale/en_US/bbbResources.properties

Afterwards rebuild your client using “ant locales”, and copy output file: en_us_resources.swf to /var/www/bigbluebutton/client/locale.

NOTE: You might need to restart the bigbluebutton server once in the end. Also I have used locale en_US for example, you should modify inside the locale you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

## To disable messages in chat area

edit `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/bigbluebutton/web-inf/class/bigbluebutton.properties`.

change the fields `defaultWelcomeMessage` and `defaultWelcomeMessageFooter` to any customized message according to your own requirements.

Restart nginx and bigbluebutton(`sudo bbb-conf --restart`)

## To disable the bigbluebutton copyright and version message

edit `/var/www/bigbluebutton-default/index.html`

scroll to the bottom of the document and edit/remove the row div in the html file.

NOTE- Before doing this you may have to change the permissions of the index file (Exp- `sudo chmod 777 /var/www/bigbluebutton-default.index.html`)

Comment: Hello, Can you please tell me how can I change the html elements? like the elements of the buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo nano /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/bigbluebutton/WEB-INF/classes/bigbluebutton.properties
```

change the fields `defaultWelcomeMessage` and `defaultWelcomeMessageFooter` to any customized message according to your own requirements.

Restart nginx and bigbluebutton

```
sudo bbb-conf --restart
```

To disable the bigbluebutton copyright and version message Line **264**

```
nano /var/www/bigbluebutton-default/index.html
```

For this, you will first have to setup a development environment, following url explains how to do this. https://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/wiki/081DevelopingBigBlueButton

Then change `bbb.mainshell.copyrightLabel2` property in `~/dev/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton–client/locale/en_US/bbbResources.properties`

Afterwards rebuild your client using

```
ant locales
```

Afterwards rebuild your client using “ant locales”, and copy output file: `en_us_resources.swf` to `/var/www/bigbluebutton/client/locale`.

Comment: Hello, Can you please tell me how can I change the html elements? like the elements of the buttons ?